# Copy elements id and put as new name with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have a list of input fields with a unique id and want to change the name attribute to be identical to each input fields ID. I have following code:

```
<script>

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

jQuery(".input-class").each(function() {

var saveId=jQuery(this).attr("id");
jQuery(".input-class").attr("name", saveId);

});

});

</script>
```

Unfortunately it takes the name of the first input field and puts it into all following. How can I reset or recheck the variable for each element?

Comment: You use `this` correctly when you get the `id`, just use it again when you apply the actual attribute.

Comment: Despite the immediate problem with your code, can you explain why you want to save the `id` value into the `name`? That smells, if you ask me. What are you doing to the IDs that you need to save them somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery(this)` should be used to give name to each one of those. When you use `jQuery(".input-class").attr("name", saveId)`, it is giving same name to all of them.

```
<script>

  jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".input-class").each(function() {

    var saveId=jQuery(this).attr("id");
    jQuery(this).attr("name", saveId);

  });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".input-class").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr("name", jQuery(this).attr("id"));
});
```

The ask is get the id for each element and set the id as name for each element.

Running `jQuery(".input-class").attr('name', jQuery(this).attr('id'))` inside a loop will cause all the instance to be changed with the first reference it can find since jQuery does not give any warning if you do it for one element or multple elements.

Let's say you had 5 elements on the page and when u do `jQuery(this).attr('id')`, you will get the first element's id on first iteration but `jQuery(".input-class").attr('name', value)` will cause it be updated for all elements

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: i have tried explaining the answer. let me know if i can give further details

Comment: This is much better. However, I recommend you to use \`backticks\` to highlight inline code. ;)

Comment: Just use a single pair of backticks. I put 3 pairs in my comment to highlight and escape backticks at the same time, but this was not a good idea... ^^

Comment: changed to `` convention. my bad, i didn't realize this while editing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".input-class").each(function() {
$(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("id"));
});

});
```